# Why is rsync taking a long time on large files that already exist?

Tags: rsync

I made a backup of one of my computer's internal drives to an external. The next time I used rsync to sync the two drives, I noticed that large (40 + GB) files that weren't modified were still taking a long time to "copy". I thought rsync looked at mod-times and file size first? Why would it take so long; as though it were using checksum?

I had originally copied the files using `rsync -rv --delete /src/path/ /dest/path/`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you are not copying the metadata (which you would do if you used `--archive` or `-a` instead of just `-r`), the metadata (timestamps, ownerships etc.) will be different between the copy and the original.  When you run `rsync` again, since the timestamps are different, the file is copied again.

So, you would instead want to use

```
rsync -ai --delete /src/path/ /dest/path
```

I'm using `-i` (`--itemize-changes`) since it also tells me *why* a file was copied.

Also note that when you do a *local* copy with `rsync`, it will *not* use its delta algorithm, but will instead behave as if `--whole-file` (or `-W`) was specified.  This is because the delta algorithm is assumed to  only be faster than a whole file transfer when transferring over a network. When using the delta algorithm, the whole file would need to be read and checksummed on both the source and target systems. Doing this locally seems a bit wasteful, so the file is just copied in full instead.

Comment: I just tested locally with a large file containing random bits, and I find that you are correct; the -a flag is necessary. This is actually kind of annoying; why would the main selling point of the tool not be its default behavior? Fortunately I can 'mend' this by recopying with the -a flag. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @DeepDeadpool Because of performance reasons, as I mentioned. You _could_ run it with `--no-whole-file` or `--no-W` if you wished to use the delta algorithm for a local transfer.

Comment: @DeepDeadpool Note also that if you're copying over a network with `-r` instead of `-a`, then, when you invoke `rsync` again, it would be forced to use the delta algorithm, whereas if you had used `-a` it could just have skipped that transfer completely.

Comment: I'm using -a and it's still dog slow...

Comment: @JosephGarvin If it's an initial copy, then all data has to be copied. Any later copy with updated data at the source, against the same destination, will be faster.

Comment: @Kusalananda I understand, I mean even with `-a` on an already complete transferred file it seems pretty slow

Comment: @JosephGarvin You may want to ask a  new question about that.